# Create image from local relative path in java

Tags: java, image, netbeans, path

I have an application in netbeans with a folder in the same directory as the application containing all the images, and I also have an attribute String in the class where I save the absolute path when I upload an image.
How can I obtain the relative path of an image inside the same jar to store it in a string?
Because then I create the image from the URL string.

Edit:

I have a jar including a logic package, a presentation package (with swing) and an image package. In the logic I've tried to do:

```
String img = new String("\src\Images\Image.jpg"):
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
Icon imagen = new ImageIcon(icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(photo.getWidth(),photo.getHeight(),Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
photo.setIcon(imagen);
```

Comment: Can you show your jar structure, including where your images are located and where your class files are located. Then show the code you've used to try to get a handle on your image resources.

Comment: You need to show us more including the actual structure of your jar, and your actual code where you try to extract the image.

Comment: Again, you will want to show us the actual structure of your jar -- you're still not doing this (why?). Also, dont pass a String into ImageIcon's constructor since that tries to get the image as a file, but rather use `ImageIO.read(...)` to get the image as a resource. If you show more of your code and more of your Jar structure, we can help you better

Answer (score 0):

Recommendations:

- Never create a new String with the `new String(...)` constructor. There's no need to do this, and you just waste resources unnecessarily. Instead simply use a String literal.
- Don't use Files to get images held inside of Jar files. Jar files do not hold Files.
- By passing a String into your ImageIcon's constructor, you're doing just that (check the API), you're trying to get the image as a File.
- Instead use `ImageIO.read(...)` and a resource to get the image.
- The resource path will all depend on your Jars structure, **something you have yet to show us**.

e.g.,

```
String path = "\Images\Image.jpg"; // this path may not be correct
InputStream imgStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(path);
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(imgStream);
// process your image here if desired
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
```